# Magento 2: I have a attribute of category collection. Need to sort the category ids

Tags: magento2

I created a category multiselect attribute in products in which I get the specific child categories of the parent category and select the category per requirement.
I just want to rearrange the order of fetching dynamically category ids on the frontend.

So I want to create an order number attribute filed where I will set the order for all categories and sort the categories from that attribute category.

Does anyone have any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please do a screenshot to get more clarification? thanks

Comment: I am loading the categories Can you please tell me how I can sort the categories by position

foreach($CatArrayValues as $value){
      $colorCatId = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($value);
$colorCatId->getName()
}

Comment: Please check my comment. Am stuck with this

Comment: you try this `addAttributeToSort` function in foreach loop

Comment: How i can do? Can you please share the code snippet

Comment: may be help you :-  $objectManager = $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$categoryFactory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory');
$categories = $categoryFactory->create()                              
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToSort('id')

foreach ($categories as $category){
    $category->getName();
}